# Is it possible to use firebase authentication to get google's organization information?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use firebase authentication to get google's organization information?

I want to control access to the application by organization.

What I want to achieve is
Get the organization of the user who is logged in to GSuite, and allow the user to use the application only if the organization matches the whitelist that we have prepared.

Furthermore, we want to control access by groups within the organization (for example, in a school, we want to change the APIs that teachers and students can access).

The problem is that you have to control access within the same domain...